# Импортирование net8

Tags: c#, .net, avalonia, .net-8

Мне нужно подключить mshtml и shdocvw . С импортом второй возникли проблемы , штатный tlbimp создал только один файл Interop.SHDocVw.dll а должен был создать еще Interop.AxSHDocVw.dll .
Если использовать AxImp.exe то все создается но для net4 . У net8 нет своего AxImp.exe и как решить проблему ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось решение есть . Нужно добавить в панель элементов сом обьект указав shdocvw.dll . Там появится Microsoft Web Browser , вот при установки в форму у вас и появятся эти два файла , не забудте поставить "внедрить типы взаимодействия" НЕТ . И оно работает в нет8.